# Admin logged out if autocomplete used in order create

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, ajax, logout

We are getting logged out in the backend at sales > order > create if we use browser autocomplete in the billing address fields. To be more specific the loadBlock action returns ajaxExpired with and ajaxRedirect to the login page.

The actions that get triggered is a change event for every field in the form that's autofilled, which results in an ajax request for each of this fields, although the data transmitted is always the same.

In one of the responses we get the mentioned ajaxExpired. Replaying the requests with curl shows the adminhtml cookie that's most likely the reason, because it's changed after each ajax request and therefor yields a race condition with parallel requests.

Just debouncing the change event as a quick fix turned out to be complicated, because the event handler depends on the target element.

Any ideas how we can workaround the problem? Except not using form autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this bug in the order create form in the backend. If a lot of Ajax requests stack because of the autocomplete feature of the browser (i.e. Chrome) it is very likely that sooner or later one of the requests returns ajaxExpired and redirects the user to the login page. Since practically any form input change in the create order screen results in a new Ajax request, you can stimulate this behaviour when selecting a shipping method, adding a product to the order or create a order comment as well. you just need to be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Flush magento cache as well as browser cache. It worked for me